# helm chart install traefik on kubernetes cluste

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I encounter this problem when installing treafik on kubernetes cluster

helm install traefik traefik/traefik --values /tmp/traefik-values.yml

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to install CRD crds/traefik.io_serverstransports.yaml: 1 error occurred:
* etcdserver: request timed out

I encounter this problem when installing traffic